# Does providing a projection argument to find() limit the data that is added to Mongo's working set?

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo, suppose I have a collection `mycollection` that has fields `a`, `b`, and `huge`.  I very frequently want to perform queries, mapreduce, updates, etc. on `a`, and `b` and very occassionally want to return `huge` in query results as well.

I know that `db.mycollection.find()` will scan the entire collection and result in Mongo attempting to add the whole collection to the working set, which may exceed the amount of RAM I have available.

If I instead call `db.mycollection.find({}, { a : 1, b : 1 })`, will this still result in the whole collection being added to the working set or only the terms of my projection?

Comment: only if it is a covered query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries which yours is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB can use something called covered queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries these allow you to load all the values from the index rather than the disk, or memory, if those documents are in memory at the time.

Be warned that you cannot use covered queries on a full table scan, the condition, projection and sort must all be within the index; i.e.:

```
db.col.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1});
db.col.find({a:1}, {_id:0, a:1, b:1})(.sort({b:1}));
```

Would work (the sort is in brackets because it is not totally needed). You can add `_id` to your index if you intend to return that too.

Map Reduce does not support covered queries, there is no way to project only a certain amount of fields into the MR, as far as I know; maybe there is some hack I do not know of. Map Reduce only supports a `$match` like operator in terms of input query with a separate parameter for the sort of the incoming query ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/ ).

Note that for updates I believe only atomic operations: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/ (excluding `findAndModify`) do not load the document into your working set, however, believe is the keyword there.

Considering you need to do both MR and normal find and update on these records I would strongly recommend you look into checking why you are paging in so much data and whether you really do need to do it that often. It seems like you are trying to do too much processing in a short and frequent amount of time.

On the other hand, if this is a script which runs every night or something then I would not worry too much about its excessive working set (i.e. score board recalc script).

Comment: Good answer... this leads me to believe that if I need infrequent access to 'huge', I am better off storing it elsewhere and storing a reference to it in 'mycollection', otherwise its presence in the collection can clobber the working set.